# Identify the duplicate in A1B1C1 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have some value in A1B1C1 column in excel and the same value is repeated in A10,B10,C10. Any excel macros for same to identify the duplicate

I have one excel sheet which contains data in bulk about 1000 records.

I have some data in A1 B1 C1 cells in the sheet.
Now the exact same data is repeated in A10 B10 C10.
How can I write a excel macros so that it will help me identify that combination of data and show popup saying invalid data

Also the data can be upto 1000 records but I need to check that A1 B1 C1 as whole and compare with other values

[image]

```
Sub FindDuplicateValues()

Dim xWs As Worksheet

Set xWs = Worksheets("VBA1")

For m = 5 To 12
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(xWs.Range("B5:B12"), xWs.Range("B" & m)) > 1 Then
xWs.Range("C" & m).Value = True
Else
xWs.Range("C" & m).Value = False
End If
Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to have two loops, the second nested within the first. Lets call the loop counters 'Outer' and 'Inner'. Loop 'Outer' reads a line at a time into three variables 'OA', 'OB', 'OC' from columns A, B and C respective. The 'Inner' loop reads each row below the last row read by the 'Outer' loop, in turn, into variables 'IA', 'IB' and 'IC', and compares each column value with the corresponding column value read by the outer loop. If all three values are equal, then you have a duplicate and you can e.g. mark it for further proc. Repeat with next inner, then repeat with next outer.

Comment: You could create a helper column with the formula `=A1&A2&A3`, then check the duplicates using this helper column.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mr. FunThomas, if it's OK with you to use a helper column ....

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim col As Integer

col = 1000 'helper column, column 1000

With Sheets("Sheet1") 'change if needed
    Set rg = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)) 'change if needed
End With

With rg.Offset(0, col - 1)
    .Value = "=concatenate(" & rg(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & "," & rg(1, 2).Address(0, 0) & "," & rg(1, 3).Address(0, 0) & ")"
    .Value = .Value
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        For Each cell In .Cells
            If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow _
                Then cell.End(xlToLeft).End(xlToLeft).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Next
    .Clear
End With

End Sub
```

Before running the sub, the data look something like this :
[image]

Please ignore the font color, it's just to show that there are two duplicates. Those duplicate cells will be filled with yellow color after running the sub :

[image]

Basically, the code just make a concatenate formula in the helper column. Apply a conditional formatting for the duplicate with yellow color, then it loop to each cell in the helper column, if the looped cell display color is yellow then it fill column A to C (the same row with the looped cell row) with yellow.

This kind of code won't work if after the last column of the data table, there is a value for something else. In other words, as seen in the image sample, there must be no data at all from column D until column XFD.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this, using a helper column, based on a concatenation function (like `TextJoin()`) and a `CountIf()`, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

The formulae are:

- `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:C1)`
- `=COUNTIF(D$1:D$10,D1)`

For your information: the conditional formatting is based on the formula `=COUNTIF(D$1:D$10,D1)>1`.